# Run script on wake from sleep mode android X86

Tags: android, android-x86

system: HP Elitebook 2740p | OS    : Android x86_64 6.0 r1

I would like to run a command that will activate during wake from sleepmode.
the exact command is 
inputattach --w8001 /dev/ttyS0 &

My issue is I have a wacom digitizer and everytime the pc falls asleep upon awake my digitizer is not responsive until I run that command.

I also had this issue on reboot but was corrected by inputing above code into line 18 under Function init_misc in the init.sh file.

Is their a file that I can add the code into to have the same effect on resume from sleep?

Answer (score 0):

I found one method of disabling sleep using a wake_lock command by placing it within the init.sh file under the function init_misc section line 19

echo lock_me > /sys/power/wake_lock

this will dim the screen but not turn off the CPU so the digitizer will remain active now.
Please let me know if this might cause any other unfavorable issues.